# Using Select on a 2d table with a criteria that accepts 3 parameters

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, filtering

I have a table

```
sets := Table[{i, j, k}, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}, {k, 1, 10}]
```

and I want to use a function that accepts three parameters and returns a boolean, as a criteria in Select. The function looks like this:

```
isPytagorean[{a_, b_, c_}] := a^2 == b^2 + c^2
```

I tried a couple of things but none of them worked. This one returns an empty list:

```
Select[sets, isPytagorean]
```

How should I use Select to get a new table of tables for which the criteria isPytagorean is met?

Comment: You'll want to `Flatten[]` `sets` first before trying `Select[]`, for starters. But for your actual problem, `FindInstance[]` might be more useful.

Comment: `Cases[sets, _?(isPytagorean), -1]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sol = Position[Map[isPytagorean, sets, {3}], True]
```

> {{5, 3, 4}, {5, 4, 3}, {10, 6, 8}, {10, 8, 6}}

```
rev = Reverse /@ Union[Sort /@ sol]
```

> {{5, 4, 3}, {10, 8, 6}}

```
isPytagorean /@ rev
```

> {True, True}

**Update**

The following is much faster:

```
Cases[PowersRepresentations[#, 2, 2] & /@ Range@100, {{0, _}, _}]
```

> {{{0, 5}, {3, 4}}, {{0, 10}, {6, 8}}}

Answer (score 1):

```
{a, b, c} /. Solve[
   a^2 == b^2 + c^2 && 1 <= a <= 10 && 1 <= b <= 10 &&  1 <= c <= 10 && {a, b, c} ∈ Integers,
   {a, b, c}
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tup = Tuples[Range[10], 3];
can = Pick[tup, Sort[#].DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, -1}].Sort[#] & /@ tup, 0]
Union[Sort /@ can]
```

yields: {{3, 4, 5}, {6, 8, 10}}